# Restricting a collapsible item to stay collapsed based on a certain click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have collapsible anchor tag (**data_1**) which when clicked toggles between collapsing and expanding a div element as shown below -

```
<a href="#href1" class="list-group-item"
data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"> 
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>
data_1
<span id="id_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span>
</a>
<div class="list-group collapse" id="href1">
   <a href="#href2">data_2</a> 
   <a href="#href2">data_3</a> 
</div>
```

It works as expected. But I want to add in some other functionality such that when I click the span element (**glyphicon-eye-open**) inside the collapsible anchor tag, a javascript method must be invoked.

I know that by adding onclick = function1() inside the span element does the trick, but it also does the expansion of the collapsible anchor tag. I don't want the anchor element to be expanded when I click the span element only. 
How do I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joshirohit66/v81gofLq/11/

```js
window.clickme = function() {
  alert("clicked span but not anchor");
  return false;
}
```

```css
.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root>.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root>.list-group>.list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root>.list-group>.list-group>.list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.list-group-item .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="list-group list-group-root well">

  <a href="#href1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> data_1
    <span id="id_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" onclick="return clickme();">
      </span>
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="href1">

    <a href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.1
    </a>

    <a href="#item-1-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.2
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? It would be easy to review and help you out :)

Comment: You just have to stop the propagation of the click event on the child span.  Then that click event will not bubble up to the anchor tag to toggle the collapse state.

Comment: @thebrownkid I added the fiddle in my question. :)

Comment: @Taplar how do I do that? Could you edit my fiddle and show that?

Comment: works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a comment to the javascript to show how/where to stop the propagation.

```js
$('.list-group-item .glyphicon').on('click', function (e) {
  //stop the propagation of the click on the icon(s)
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('clicked span but not anchor');
});
```

```css
.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root>.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root>.list-group>.list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root>.list-group>.list-group>.list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.list-group-item .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="list-group list-group-root well">

  <a href="#href1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i> data_1
    <span id="id_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
      </span>
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="href1">

    <a href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.1
    </a>

    <a href="#item-1-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.2
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```